# Bibliography with hyperref package

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, citing

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sfbold,nocenter,twoside]{thesis}
\usepackage{filecontents}  
\usepackage[inner=3.7cm,outer=2cm,top=5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,epsf}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.27in} \setlength{\textheight}{8in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx} \makeindex
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\thesistitle}{Scotland v Wales starts pivotal weekend}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{CMS,
author = {Mary},
title = {Scotland v Wales starts pivotal weekend},
journal = {BBC},
year = {2003},
OPTkey = {•},
volume = {69},
number = {3--4},
pages = {~871--887},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
@Book{EN,
author = {Adam},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {Scotland v Wales starts pivotal weekend},
publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
year = {2000},
OPTkey = {•},
OPTvolume = {•},
OPTnumber = {•},
series = {BBX},
address = {New York},
OPTedition = {•},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\doublespacing

\pagestyle{empty}

\vspace{5cm}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE \bfseries \thesistitle}
\end{center}

\vspace{5cm}
\begin{center}
{\Large \bfseries Leonhard Euler}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
{\large \bfseries School of Somewhere}
\end{center}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\centerline{\large \bfseries 2017}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\begin{center}
{\LARGE \bfseries \thesistitle}
\end{center}

\vspace{5cm}

\begin{center}
{ \bfseries \Large Leonhard Euler}
\end{center}

\vspace{6cm}
\centerline{\large \bf School of Somewhere}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{center}
\bf
A thesis submitted to the School of Somewhere
\end{center}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\centerline{\large \bfseries 2017}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\newpage
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
A thousand thanks...
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\chapter*{List of Works}
\section*{Publications}
\section*{Conferences}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\chapter*{Notations}\markboth{Notations}{}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap:introduction}
\section{Introduction 1}
I wan to cite \cite{CMS} and \cite{EN}.
\section{Introduction 2}

\section{Introduction 3}

\section{Introduction 4}\label{F-space}
\subsection{Introduction 4-1}
\subsection{Introduction 4-2}

\section{Structure of the thesis}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\label{chap:ch2-wcos-C1}

\section{Chapter 2-1}
\subsection{Chapter 2-1-1}
\subsection{Chapter 2-1-2}
\subsection{Chapter 2-1-3}

\section{Chapter 2-2}
\subsection{Chapter 2-2-1}
\subsection{Chapter 2-2-2}
\subsection{Chapter 2-2-3}

\chapter{Chapter 3}\label{chap:ch3-cso-semi}
\section{Chapter 3-1}

\section{Chapter 3-2}
\subsection{Chapter 3-2-1}
\subsection{Chapter 3-2-2}

\section{Chapter 3-3}

\section{Chapter 3-4}

\section{Chapter 3-5}
\subsection{Chapter 3-5-1}
\subsection{Chapter 3-5-2}
\subsection{Chapter 3-5-3}

\section{Chapter 3-6}
\subsection{Chapter 3-6-1}
\subsection{Chapter 3-6-2}



\chapter{Chapter 4}\label{chap:ch4-wcos-Cn}

\section{Chapter 4-1}
\subsection{Chapter 4-1-1}
\subsection{Chapter 4-1-2}
\subsection{Chapter 4-1-3}
\subsection{Chapter 4-1-4}

\section{Chapter 4-2}
\subsection{Chapter 4-2-1}
\subsection{Chapter 4-2-2}
\subsection{Chapter 4-2-3}




\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{\jobname} 
\emph{Note that the last number is used to indicate the pages citing references.}

\appendix

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{appendix}
\markboth{appendix}
Not since 2007 have Vern Cotter's men won a Six Nations match against Wales, with the average margin of defeat 15 points in that period. Ireland have recalled Lions fly-half Jonny Sexton as they look to re-establish themselves in the title race with a win over a resurgent France. And Sexton's main rival to be the Lions' 10 this summer, Owen Farrell, will lead unbeaten England out against the Azzuri at Twickenham on Sunday as he wins his 50th cap in arguably his most impressive championship yet.
\label{chap:Appendix}
\section{appendix 1}
\section{appendix 2}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

After running by Texmaker, I get the Bibliography as

```
BIBLIOGRAPHY
[1] Adam. Scotland v Wales starts pivotal weekend. BBX. Springer-Verlag, New York, 2000. [1]
[2] Mary. Scotland v wales starts pivotal weekend. BBC, 69(3{4): 871{887, 2003. [1]
Note that the last number is used to indicate the pages citing references.
```

In my code, the page 1 starts from section Introduction. When I click the number [1] (last number) in each paper of Bibliography, the cover page displays (not page 1 of Introduction). I do not why this happens.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Welcome! No need to shout.

Comment: Load `hyperref` last. Which of the zillion versions of `thesis.cls`? Don't lie to `geometry` like that - it isn't nice and your layout will not look nice either.

Comment: `\setcounter{page}{1}` is the problem. This means that page `1` is written to the `.aux` file for those citations. `hyperref` no doubt complains to you on the console and in the log, warning you about multiply defined labels or some such. That's why. *Which* page 1 should the link jump to? `hyperref` can't tell. You don't need to reset the counter yourself anyway. (But I don't know if the automatic reset will break the links.)

Comment: Completely unrelated to the problem, but there are several things in the code you've posted that do not follow 'best practices'. For example, you load `geometry` then later set the page dimensions (with `\setlength`); just use geometry. Don't use `\bf` but `\bfseries`; don't use `\centreline`. Look at how you are using the `center` environment and be consistent. Etc., etc.

Comment: The code looks like hours and hours of time invested using google and finding old, very old, posts. Why didn't you invest less time in reading a modern introduction to LaTeX? Your pagenumbering scheme is dodgy, some pacages you load are obsolete for years, You are doing strange stuff with unnumbered chapters, the titlepage looks strange etc. Apart from that, quite good example for a start.

Comment: There's no need for `{\Large ...}` if it is used in a `center` environment and there's no other content than that... it's already grouped. The loading of `hyperref` should come at the end of the preamble, not somewhere  in the middle

Comment: The issue vanishes if the patch from an answer to this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187907/hyperref-is-pointing-always-to-the-first-page-of-the-document/355883#355883 is applied and `\setcounter{page}{1}` is replaced in the first case by `\pagenumbering{arabic}` and removed completely after `\pagenumbering{roman}` where it is redundant anyway, since `\pagenumbering` always resets the page number. However, there are so many bad things in this 'document'...

Comment: Is there any news here?