# Problem when contents go over two pages

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, warnings

When the table of contents go over two pages I get this warning:

> destination with the same identifier (name{page.i}) has been already
>   used, duplicate ignored \relax l.36
>   ...on}{\numberline {5.6}test}{9}{section.5.6} [1])pdfTeX warning
>   (ext4): d

If the document is not so long we don't get a warning, for example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}




\title{Test}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{titlingpage}
    \maketitle
    \end{titlingpage}

\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}



\end{document}
```

However if we increase the document so that the contents go over several pages we get the warning, an example of a document giving the warning is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}




\title{Test}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{titlingpage}
    \maketitle
    \end{titlingpage}

\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}



\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I bet this is ***not*** an error. I bet it is a warning. An error stops compilation. Does your code not compile?

Comment: Ok, I changed the word to "warning", it compiles.

Answer (score 2):

The main culprit for the error is the `titlingpage` environment, which explicitly resets the page number with `\setcounter{page}{\@ne}` -- this confuses the hyperanchors set by `hyperref`.

In a similar answer I kept track of such page numbering changes (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355883/31729), here I used the same method, adapted for the `titlingpage` environment, by patching `\mem@titlingpage` and its 'friend' `\endmem@titlingpage`.

In the very end, this removes the warnings and provides correct hyperanchors as long as no other explicit `\setcounter{page}` manipulations occur.

Another possible solution (untested, however): Use the `hypertexnames=false` option to `hyperref` or in `\hypersetup`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcounter{pagenumberingcalls}
\newcommand{\pagenumberingchanges}{\thepagenumberingcalls}

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xpretocmd{\pagenumbering}{\edef\@previouspagenumberingcalls{\thepagenumberingcalls}\stepcounter{pagenumberingcalls}}{}{}

\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \xpatchcmd{\Hy@EveryPageAnchor}{%
    \hyper@@anchor{page.\@the@H@page}%
  }{%
    \hyper@@anchor{page.\pagenumberingchanges.\@the@H@page}%
  }{\typeout{Patch 1 succeeded}}{\typeout{Patch failure for EveryPageAnchor}}
  \xpatchcmd{\Hy@EveryPageAnchor}{%
    \hyper@@anchor{page.\the\c@page}%
  }{%
    \hyper@@anchor{page.\pagenumberingchanges.\the\c@page}%
  }{\typeout{Patch 2 succeeded}}{}
  \xpatchcmd{\Hy@EveryPageAnchor}{%
    \hyper@@anchor{page.\the\Hy@pagecounter}%
  }{%
    \hyper@@anchor{page.\pagenumberingchanges.\the\Hy@pagecounter}%
  }{\typeout{Patch 3 succeeded}}{}
  }{%Nope, no hyperref loaded --> just be silent%
  }


\xpatchcmd{\mem@titlingpage}{%
  \if\mem@titlpg@reset\setcounter{page}{\@ne}\fi
}{%
  \if\mem@titlpg@reset\stepcounter{pagenumberingcalls}\setcounter{page}{\@ne}\fi
}{\typeout{Successfully patched \string\mem@titlingpage}}{}


\xpatchcmd{\endmem@titlingpage}{%
   \if\mem@titlpg@reset\setcounter{page}{\@ne}\fi
 }{%
   \if\mem@titlpg@reset\stepcounter{pagenumberingcalls}\setcounter{page}{\@ne}\fi
 }{\typeout{Successfully patched \string\endmem@titlingpage}}{}
}



\makeatother


\title{Test}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{titlingpage}
  \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the warning you only need to fool hyperref during the first two pages with a suitable `\pagenumbering`. Anything different than `arabic` and `roman` which are used afterwards.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\title{Test}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{titlingpage}
    \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter


\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\end{document}
```